# Use spark-sql cli to load csv data directly into parquet table

Tags: csv, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a csv file and would like to load it into a parquet file on my hard drive, then run SQL queries against it using the spark-sql CLI. Is there a spark-sql command or two that would do this?

If spark-sql is not the right method, then what would you suggest is the simplest way to load csv into parquet? After this step, my next task is to run sql queries on the data

Comment: If spark-sql is not the right method, then what would you suggest is the simplest way to load csv into parquet? After this step, my next task is to run sql queries on the data

Comment: Rather than adding details in comments, please [edit] your question with that information. Comments here may get hidden by "show more comments" or could be deleted without notice.  Editing updates into your question ensures that they don't get lost and that everybody who wants to answer the question sees them.

Comment: Thanks. I have moved my comment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
package spark

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, trim}

object csv2parquet extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("CSV-Parquet")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._
  val sourceFile = "/<path file>/test.csv" // bad data in file
  val targetFile = "/<path file>/testResult.parquet"
  // read csv file
  val df1 = spark.read.option("header", false).csv(sourceFile)
  df1.show(false)
  //    +-------+-------+----------+-----------+
  //    |_c0    |_c1    |_c2       |_c3        |
  //    +-------+-------+----------+-----------+
  //    |Header |TestApp|2020-01-01|null       |
  //    |name   | dept  | age      | batchDate |
  //    |john   | dept1 | 33       | 2020-01-01|
  //    |john   | dept1 | 33       | 2020-01-01|
  //    |john   | dept1 | 33       | 2020-01-01|
  //    |john   | dept1 | 33       | 2020-01-01|
  //    |Trailer|count  |4         |null       |
  //    +-------+-------+----------+-----------+

  // write data to parquet. 
  df1.write.mode("append").parquet(targetFile)

  val resDF = spark.read.parquet(targetFile)
  resDF.show(false)
  //          +-------+-------+----------+-----------+
  //          |_c0    |_c1    |_c2       |_c3        |
  //          +-------+-------+----------+-----------+
  //          |Header |TestApp|2020-01-01|null       |
  //          |name   | dept  | age      | batchDate |
  //          |john   | dept1 | 33       | 2020-01-01|
  //          |john   | dept1 | 33       | 2020-01-01|
  //          |john   | dept1 | 33       | 2020-01-01|
  //          |john   | dept1 | 33       | 2020-01-01|
  //          |Trailer|count  |4         |null       |
  //          +-------+-------+----------+-----------+
  // try sql
  resDF
    .filter(trim(col("_c2")).equalTo(33))
    .select(col("_c2"))
    .show(false)
    //          +---+
    //          |_c2|
    //          +---+
    //          | 33|
    //          | 33|
    //          | 33|
    //          | 33|
    //          +---+
}
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation as why you write the output parquet file multiple times? Or update the code? Thank you.

Comment: 1. only for received many rows for example.
2. you need have only one command df1.write.mode("append").parquet(targetFile) or if you use table you can use ....format("parquet").saveAsTable(....)